# Convert to Text Box search instead of drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, full-text-search

I've been using this script to bring back information from a drop down select option, i want to use this same method but in a text box, where the user can input a search instead, is this possible to do? It would be a search engine of sorts. I think i can figure out how to create the search engine part, I just need to covert this first to make sure i can return back a proper result.

My objective is to Allow the user to type in a text field a specific logo he/she wants, and the return is the results of that search. They are searching png images in an array and will select one to complete the form.

```
function showSub(str) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (str=="") {
      document.getElementById("txtSub").innerHTML="";
      return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("txtSub").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getSub.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(str),true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Html

```
<tr>
  <td width='15%'><div align='right'><strong>Sub-Category</strong></div></td>
  <td width='70%'><div id="txtSub"></div></td>
</tr>
```

Side note: I've seen search queries that give you results on the fly and results that give you results after pressing enter. My current script that uses this is in ajax I believe and gives you the results after the drop down is selected, would it possible to do the same with a text search box?

Edit: Also, if this script is the wrong method to do this, and someone has an alternate suggestion or a script that already does this, i'm very open to other ideas. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a text field input you could do something like:

html

```
<input type="text" id="searchText" value="" />
```

javascript/jquery

```
$(document).on('change', '#searchText', function() {
    // Get the search text
    var searchText = $(this).val();
    // Make sure it isn't empty
    if (searchText.length > 0) {
        // Send the update request
        showSub(searchText);
    }
});
```

Comment: The on change event is fired any time the value of the text box changes. When it changes, you send the request with the new search text to update the data.

Comment: Where does the script send a requests to a php page in order to actually do the search?

Comment: using the showSub function you already posted, is that not what you are using to make the requests?

Comment: So this script would work with my script for it to function? it's not a stand alone sort of thing?

Comment: Yes, it would need your ajax request to get the data from the server.